# Implementing a Python file in Django

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I'm pretty new to Django and html. I want to import the following code in Django:

```
import csv

with open('FILE.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    CSVFILE = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

df = pd.DataFrame(CSVFILE, columns= ['A','B','C','D'])
while 1>0:
    select_color = df.loc[df['A'] == input()]
    print (select_color)
```

What I want to achieve, is a webpage with a form, where you can fill in "A", which would thereafter display 'A','B','C','D'.
What is the best way to treat this?

Comment: hey maurits! can u give me more context? are u willing to render this csv data in an html page?

Comment: Hi gbrennon, thanks for reaching out! I'm willing to do whatever, I just need to display the rows ('A','B','C','D') of the CSV file that are corresponding with the given input ('A').

Answer (score 0):

first things first!

i'll guide u with this issue, but we need to discuss some things before...

guidance related to the "no-django code":

1. u have a csv file, basically some spreadsheet file, and ur naming the columns as "A", "B", "C" and "D". what does "A" column mean in this spreadsheet? and "B"? u should change those names to match their real meaning. if this the "A" column represents the "name" data u should rename it to "name"
2. u are reading this file with the `csv.reader` and casting it to a list. try using the DictReader(https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
3. u are using an infinite loop through the usage of  `while 1>0` to ask the user some input and try to find any answer...

what u should try to write as code:

1. implement a django view that receives in its "GET" request the arguments that will tell u which "color" the "user" is willing to find.
2. use this "color" to search in the database for the desired result
3. return it to the user

all of these "http" details are not related to django, but to web knowledge.

Comment: Hi gbrennon, just to clear things up:
1. ABCD are fill-ins for the columns in question, which would be ['Klantnummer','Huisnummer','Postcode','Polisnummer']. 
2. I will look into this, thanks!
3. Speaks for itself.

Thanks a lot for the feedback, I will figure it out!

Comment: I'm using the following code:




`import csv
from csv import reader

with open('/home/maurits/PolisCheck/check/PolisLists/PolisCheck.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    PolisCheck = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in PolisCheck:
       PolisData = ([col + '=' + row[col] for col in reader.fieldnames])
       `
On Windows, this works fine. But on Linux (Ubuntu) I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'".
I've tried Googling the issue, but I don't seem to find anything. Could you please hit me up with feedback?